# How to import IntelliJ project into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I am trying to export a java project from IntelliJ to Eclipse by using the "export to eclipse" option in IntelliJ but I get the following error:

> "Eclipse incompatible modules found" in a dialog box occured.

How can I solve it?

Comment: The long term solution to sharing projects between IDE's is to use Maven.

Answer (score 1):

To convert an IntelliJ IDEA module to the Eclipse-compatible format, follow these steps:

- On the main menu, choose "File" | "Project Structure", or press "Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S".
- In the "Project Structure Dialog" dialog, select the module you want to convert.
- Switch to the "Dependencies Tab" tab.
- From the Dependencies storage format drop-down list, select Eclipse (.classpath).